# How do I get this cookie into a PHP variable?

Tags: php, cookies

I can see it is there, but can't figure out the syntax to get it out? When I issue the following:

print_r( $_COOKIE );

The response looks like this. How do I get it out?

```
[HonoluluRealEstate] => Array
    (
        ["ListPriceMin"] => 800000
    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo $_COOKIE["HonoluluRealEstate"]["ListPriceMin"];
```

Feel tired after making so much effort :) And I can bet 5 cents that that is not the actual output of `print_r` or else those quotation marks wouldn't be there.

Comment: *"Feel tired after making so much effort"* - Time for a Coffee Crisp then. Put your feet up ;-)

Comment: *"And I can bet 5 cents..."* - a whole nickel? I'll raise that to a dime.

Comment: what are their stocks worth today?

Comment: OK, maybe I saved the cookie wrong and that is why I can't get it out. The quotation marks are actually there and the answer above does not work, probably because I saved it wrong. Here is how I saved it.

setcookie ('HonoluluRealEstate["ListPriceMin"]', $_REQUEST['ListPriceMin'], time()+(3600*24*365),"/");

Comment: 236.73 Oops that's a big bet now.

Comment: OK, thanks, that solved the issue. I should not have put the quotes around the ListPriceMin when I saved the cookie. Once I removed the quotes and saved it without the quotes, then the above code worked. Thanks!!!

Comment: Wow thank God my bitcoin stays intact :) Fred drinks are on me tonight